# Hibernate create table with name escaped

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Entity class like the following:

```
@Entity
public class perm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private boolean add;

    // Getter & Setter are also there ...
}
```

When I start spring (with JPA hibernate), he generates the following CREATE TABLE statement for my MySQL database:

```
create table perm (id bigint not null auto_increment, add bit not null, primary key (id))
```

This create will fail, because the column name `add` is not escaped with

```
`
```

like it normally should be.
Normally I would create it manually with the following code:

```
create table perm (`id` bigint not null auto_increment, `add` bit not null, primary key (`id`))
```

Of course I could create a `ImprovedNamingStrategy` in order to manipulate all the column names by setting a prefix or suffix to them. But then **all** my columns have this syntax.

Now my question:
Is there maybe a jpaProperty that escapes a column name, everytime it is used inside a sql syntax? At first I thought, that this will already be done, when I set my

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");`
```

But apparently this is not the case. Maybe there is another setting for this?

Answer (score 2):

Add @Column annotation to the field:

```
@Entity
public class perm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="`add`")
    private boolean add;

    // Getter & Setter are also there ...
}
```

Also consider using a better name for the column. This may cause problems somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

`add` is a reserved keyword in Mysql as you can see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

You are better to avoid using it. Using `isAdded` may be an alternative.

In case you cannot change the column name, use this to instruct Hibernate:

```
@Column(name="[add]")
private boolean add;
```

Comment: I know this. But like I said in my question: I do not want to change this specific column name, nor all column names by a naming strategy. I want hibernate to escape column names correctly. Because I can not afford to run into a similar error in the future. This kind of "error" is not reported in the console. hibernate generates the tables and does not say anything about not creating the single one.

Comment: Using `@Column(name="[add]")`, Hibernate will escape your column name correctly.

Comment: Also, this is not Hibernate issue. Each database has a different list of reserved keywords so you need to handle it yourself.